# Using get in jQuery to load an html form with PHP variables

Tags: php, jquery, forms, get, undefined

I have an `index.php` that includes `config.php`. Now I'm using `$.get()` when I click a button to load a form:

```
$.get('form.php', function (form) {
    $(form).insertAfter();
});
```

This form requires `config.php` for some input values; however, when the form has loaded, I receive the php error:

`Notice: Undefined variable: config in form.php on line 27`

Line 27 of `form.php`: `if ($config['spam_protect']) {`

I realize the config.php has already been instantiated when the page initially loads, thus I suspect this to be the problem I'm having. I've tried including `config.php` within the `form.php` file to no avail. Tips or tricks anyone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice: Undefined variable: config in form.php on line 27

The message is quite clear: `$config` isn't loaded, maybe because your config file doesn't load correctly.

Note that if you make an Ajax request, the script requested in that request is *an entirely new PHP instance*. You may need to include `config.php` in that one as well.

Comment: Could you have a peak at my reply on vassilis comment, same answer you gave. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either `form.php` doesn't include `config.php`, or `config.php` doesn't declare `$config`

Answer (score 0):

You **should** be including `config.php` in `form.php` if it's needed.

Calling it through ajax has nothing to do with index.php, it's run independently.

That being said, we need some more info on this one.

Comment: Understandable. I did this successfully now, however it (`form.php`) requires a class which is already being declared and required in `index.php` so yet another error.

Comment: @Ryan then you need to change the structure of your script. The AJAX request you make is completely independent, as @vassilis says. You'll need to move your classes to a central location and incude them from there

Comment: @Pekka is right, but you can go around this by using `if class_exists('your_class')` to avoid including it the second time.